# LinkedIn API OAuth2 Authentication with scope permission failure

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to retrieve a accesstoken for the linkedInAPI to post and retrieve shares.For that I am authentication the linkedIn API auth by specifing the scope

> r_member_social w_member_social r_basicprofile

but the authentication URL is failing with error

> Scope "r_member_social" is not authorized for your
>   application.

Why is my app does not authorize r_member_social, what should I do to authorize it ?

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing `r_member_social` requires special approval from LinkedIn.

To gain access to `r_member_social`, you first need to apply to and be approved for the [LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program).

Then, submit your request for `r_member_social` via the [LinkedIn Developer Partner Support Site](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us). They'll know how to help get you approved. However, they may not approve you - the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api) state that `r_member_social` "is granted to select developers only."

Answer (score -2):

In V2 w_member_social replaced with w_share
Plese check the document 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: No. The docs state that "w_member_social (replaces w_share)". OP is asking about `r_member_social`.